# Join giving two rows instead of one

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have this join:

```
select first_name, last_name, photo_path, private_messages, mid_thumb, 
bio_blurb, user_email 
from users 
left join member_photo on users.user_id = member_photo.photo_member_id 
left join user_email_options on users.user_id = user_email_options.email_user_id 
where user_id = 2
```

For some reason, it gives two rows instead of 1 row that I expected with the users information.  Is there anything obvious that I am missing?  I have done a bunch of left joins before and never seem to have encountered this.  Why would I get 2 items in the result set?

Here is what happens on the page for example:

http://www.comehike.com/community/hiker_public_profile.php?community_member_id=2

See - two records.

Comment: I think it would depend on the data in your table... I expect that you've checked, but what happens when you run a count on each table individually where user_id = 2?

Comment: What kind of indexes are defined for the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like `member_photo` or `user_email_options` has more than one row corresponding to user_id 2

Comment: yes, they do - its user id, and each of the 3 tables that are joined has it.  But I figured it would just be one row.

Comment: @Genadinik, what I meant to say was, either member_photo.photo_member_id has more than one row with a value of 2, or user_email_options.email_user_id has more than one row with a value of 2

Comment: ah yes, helped me find a bug! Thank you!